# Could not eliminate Null by having clause

Tags: mysql

```
select ID, "a" col, a value from yourtable
union all
select ID, "b" col, b value from yourtable
union all
select ID, "c" col, c value from yourtable
having value is not Null;
```

As far as I known, having clause is used after doing summary
but after running this, why there is still Null in value field?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a derived table and filter the final output from the union. You can try something like:

```
select * 
from (
(
   select ID, "a" col, a as `value` 
   from yourtable
)     
  union all
(
   select ID, "b" col, b as `value` 
   from yourtable
)  
 union all

(
  select ID, "c" col, c as `value` 
  from yourtable
) 
    ) as t1 
where `value` is not null ;
```